# Trying to write an Eratosthenes Sieve in Python. Is this correct and how can I make it faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sieve-of-eratosthenes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to list all primes below N in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python)

I have not been doing programming for very long, and I'm just doing this for fun, and I don't know much advanced Python, but...
I wrote this, and I wanted to know whether it is actually an Eratosthenes Sieve program, and if it is, how could I make it faster. I don't really want someone to post a program that is a solution, but more tell me how I could adapt mine.

```
def eratSieve(n):
    all = []
    for a in range(2, n+1):
        all.append(a)               
    for b in all:                       
        for i in range(2,int(round(len(all)/b))):
            while i*b in all:
                all.remove(i*b)
                i+=1
    return all
```

Thanks for your help.

BTW - It's in Python 2.7

Comment: I think you should take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work right.

The main problem is that you loop on all the value in `all` and in the `while` you remove some element from `all`.

This way some value in `all` are not considered, so the function does not remove all the non-prime numbers

Try to execute it for n=100 and the result you get is

`2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99`

while it should be

`2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97`
(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)

Also, the range of the second `for` is wrong, since you consider the lenght of the list, not the current value of `b` and so you check for multiple of 2 only in the first 50 values, the multiple of 3 in the first 17, 5 in the first 9 and so on. From `b = 13` you never enter in the inner `for`, since `int(round(len(all)/b)) = 1` and so you have something like `for i in range(2,1)`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gianluca, and I have a possible solution: keep your main array (`all`) as bools and mark non-primes, but don't remove them. It might also be faster, because you don't change list size.

Minor thing: you can just write `all = range(2, n+1)` in the beginning if you want to keep it as ints.

Answer (score 0):

Your method produces incorrect results.  The error lies in the `for i` loop.  Here it is, adjusted, and with a test:

```
known_primes = [
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,
31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,
73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,
127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,
179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,
233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,
283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,
353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,
419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,
467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,
547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,
607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,
661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,
739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,
811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,
877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,
947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997,1009,1013,
1019,1021,1031,1033,1039,1049,1051,1061,1063,1069,
1087,1091,1093,1097,1103,1109,1117,1123,1129,1151,
1153,1163,1171,1181,1187,1193,1201,1213,1217,1223,
1229,1231,1237,1249,1259,1277,1279,1283,1289,1291,
1297,1301,1303,1307,1319,1321,1327,1361,1367,1373,
1381,1399,1409,1423,1427,1429,1433,1439,1447,1451,
1453,1459,1471,1481,1483,1487,1489,1493,1499]
def eratSieve(n):
    all = []
    for a in range(2, n+1):
        all.append(a)               
    for b in all:                       
        for i in all[all.index(b):]:
            while i*b in all:
                all.remove(i*b)
                i+=1
    return all

for N in range(1500):
    for n in eratSieve(N):
        if n not in known_primes:
            print N,n
```

Comment: Are you sure it work ? The output of the function `eratSieve` for `n=100` is `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73,79, 83, 89, 97, 99]`

Comment: You're right, it needs a `+1` in that loop.  I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
def primes(N):
    primes = [x for x in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13) if x < N]
    if N < 17: return primes
    candidators = [x for x in xrange((N - 2) | 1, 15, -2)
                    if x % 3 and x % 5 and x % 7 and x % 11 and x % 13]
    top = int(N ** 0.5)
    while (top + 1) * (top + 1) <= N: top += 1
    while True:
        p = candidators.pop()
        primes.append(p)
        if p > top: break
        candidators = filter(p.__rmod__, candidators)
    candidators.reverse()
    primes.extend(candidators)
    return primes
```

I think this code would work faster...